# Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vbroadcastss'

Tags: python, compiler-errors, avx, avx2

I'm trying to install [annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy) via `pip install annoy` on a CentOS 6.5 server, but got the following errors. Any idea? I found `VBROADCASTSS` in [here](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/VBROADCAST.html), but still have no idea how to fix these error.

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/xxx/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/include/python2.7 -c src/annoymodule.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/annoymodule.o -O3 -march=native -ffast-math
cc1plus: warning: command line option '-Wstrict-prototypes' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
In file included from /home/xxx/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                 from src/annoymodule.cc:16:
/home/xxx/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1188:0: warning: "_POSIX_C_SOURCE" redefined
 #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200112L
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28:0,
                 from src/annoylib.h:18,
                 from src/annoymodule.cc:15:
/usr/include/features.h:162:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 # define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
 ^
In file included from /home/xxx/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                 from src/annoymodule.cc:16:
/home/xxx/.pyenv/versions/2.7.10/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:1210:0: warning: "_XOPEN_SOURCE" redefined
 #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28:0,
                 from src/annoylib.h:18,
                 from src/annoymodule.cc:15:
/usr/include/features.h:164:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 # define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
 ^

/tmp/ccfNu0mQ.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccfNu0mQ.s:21160: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vbroadcastss'
/tmp/ccfNu0mQ.s:21163: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vbroadcastss'
/tmp/ccfNu0mQ.s:21532: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vbroadcastss'
/tmp/ccfNu0mQ.s:24347: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vbroadcastss'
/tmp/ccfNu0mQ.s:24350: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vbroadcastss'
/tmp/ccfNu0mQ.s:24718: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `vbroadcastss'
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use `gcc -march=native -Q --help=target` to compare the gcc settings on several Linux machines.
I find out the main difference is that the `-march` line on the failed machine is `haswell`, and others are
something like `core...`. Here's is the corresponding outputs from other servers:

`CentOS release 6.5 (Final)` - `-march=corei7-avx`

`CentOS Linux 7 (Core)` - `-march=core-avx-i`

`Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)` - `-march=core-avx2`

I guess the errors come from the different instruction sets gcc used.
In annoy's `setup.py`, the `-march=native` in line `extra_compile_args=['-O3', '-march=native', '-ffast-math']` means gcc will attempt to detect the processor and automatically set appropriate flags for it.
So I change this flag to `-march=corei7-avx` in `setup.py` and the errors gone.

See `-march` in [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.3/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html#i386-and-x86_002d64-Options) for details if you are interested.

## Updates

After confirming with the server admins, this error is due to the CentOS loader software being older than the new Haswell CPUs in the server. Installing a recent version of `binutils` package can also solve the problem.

Comment: AVX introduced `vbroadcastss ymm, [m32]`, but AVX2 introduced `vbroadcastss ymm, xmm` to broadcast the low element of the source vector.  Presumably with `-march=haswell`, (avx2), the code generated some asm that your old binutils couldn't assemble.  (And because of this quirk of vbroadcastss, you got "invalid operands" rather than "unrecognized instruction".)

Comment: You can at least use `-mtune=haswell`.  But generating slower code that avoids AVX2 to work around your old toolchain seems like a poor idea.  Of course, using a newer compiler as well as assembler would be good, because newer compilers are generally better at auto-vectorizing for new instruction sets, i.e. they can make faster/better code from the same source.

Answer (score 1):

Your version of binutils is too old to support AVX/AVX2 instructions, which have been detected as available on your processor. 
You need binutils 2.22 or newer for AVX support.